# SQL фильтрация дубликатов

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Вопрос заключается в следующем :
Есть база данных postgre, в ней есть таблица вот такого вида
[image: Тут таблица]
Из за сбоя в службе которая собирает статистику , я получил дублирование записей,
выглядит это примерно вот так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Время (timestamp'ы) и сupid остаются прежними ,а кол-во деталей уменьшается

Суть в том ,что мне нужно составить запрос ,который бы подчистил бы базу ,удалив дубликаты вместе с сведениями о деталях произведенных работником за эту смену.

т.е ,удалять надо вот такими блоками :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

стандартный group by ,которым заполнен интернет , тут не работает

поэтому буду благодарен за любую помощь.

P.S Деталей не обязательно 3 , может быть выпущено только одно наименование за смену. Дублирующие записи не расположены по порядку ,а хаотично раскиданы по таблице.
размер таблицы примерно 4000 записей

Comment: Не, а где дубли-то? Все показанные записи - уникальны...

Comment: _mysql_ при чём тут?

Comment: @Akina дубли на 2 скрине 
oper и timestamp и opensessiontimestmp и cupid повторяются

Comment: через select отберите повторяющиеся поля по идентичным записям, удалите имеющие наибольший идентификатор, поставьте ограничение на базу, чтоб больше такого не происходило

Comment: @alex обратите внимание на последний скриншот.
мне нужно убирать целые блоки из 3-4 строк. 
если сделать просто select distinct то строки с наименованием деталей ,останутся в базе

Comment: @alex прошу прощения, сейчас подправлю вопрос. 
Иерархия записей такая 
есть смена работника , она содержит в себе данные смены и общее кол-во деталей , затем следуют строки с детальным описанием сколько деталей было изготовлено 
cupid - ид рабочего места

Comment: @Siberian Wolfs, а построчно нельзя сравнить по cupid и detailname? cupid меняется вообще?

Comment: @ alex все поля могут меняться.
Построчно сравнить можно ,наверно,
поделитесь примером?

Comment: @Siberian Wolfs, у вас нарушена атомарность данных. Вы в одну таблицу кладете операции и итог по ним.  Так не делается. С запросом сейчас помочь не смогу

Comment: @alex я знаю что так не делается, не я проектировал эту базу.
ко мне пришли когда все сломалось ,и сделать это все надо еще вчера

Answer (score 1):

Что-то типа такого:

```sql
DELETE FROM your_table AS t1
 USING your table AS t2
 WHERE t1.oper = t2.oper
   AND t1.cupid = t2.cupid
   AND t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
   AND t1.detailname = t2.detailname
   AND t1.opensessiontimestmp = t2.opensessiontimestmp
   AND t1.id > t2.id
```

Условия уникальности подставьте свои.